# Unset cookie Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How can I delete or destroy cookie in Laravel 4?

I have created it using the next code:

`return Response::make('', 302, array('Location' => $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))->withCookie($cookie);`

But in the end, I need to destroy this data.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to use Cookie::forget like this:

```
$cookie = Cookie::forget('cookieKey');

return Response::make('foo')->withCookie($cookie);
```

remember **you have to always return the cookie with the response**, it's not like Session.

Answer (score 2):

Im pretty sure its the `forget()` method..

So in your case....when $cookie was made it was given a name, just unset it like so

```
Cookie::forget('yourCookie');
```

Comment: I have tried it like this (and it should work, since it is in documentation) but it won't work. In the end I did another Request to set up the same cookie with value of NULL. Not really the best solution but it works.

Comment: While this is the right direction, Amir's answer below has the key piece of the puzzle. Cookie::forget() only makes a new cookie with null value and negative expiration--you still have to actually send it to the client to remove their cookie.

Comment: Crypt::setKey( Config::get('app.key') );
When using your own keys in crypting, reset the app.key first.

Comment: @VukStanković you may want to change the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @Amir

Answer (score 1):

[image: here is a list of frequently used with cookie]
    here is a list of frequently used with cookies .
    u could check the detail on Laravel Api document . [2]http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Cookie.CookieJar.html

wish u good luck !